# How to inject a Laravel route into a js file that is packaged up in webpack?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I have a js file that checks if a username is available. I have a reusable ajax class that I post data to and listen for the results. This class is reusable and only takes a url as an initialization parameter. So if I want to check if an  email is free, I can pass it my Laravel route for checking emails. The module that checks for the username has been packaged up into its on IIFE (though I am open to suggestions on a different implementation).

Currently, I have the entire check username in its own js file that gets bundled up with WebPack.

Currently I keep my initialization outside webpack and in my html

```
<script>
    let apiQuery = new CustomLib.ApiQuery('{{route('users.name.availability')}}');
</script>
```

Now if I want to hardcode the URL, I can move the above initialization to the `_username_availability`

But that defeats the purpose, in my opinion, of using named routes. Since my dev and production servers have complete different urls.

How can I either inject the url into *_username_availability* so I can package up my username functionally? Or is how I am doing it the best solution?

**_username_availability.js**

```
$(function () {
    apiQuery.subscribe(results);

    mybutton.on('change', function(e){
        apiQuery.search($(this).val());
    });

    function results(data){
        //.. Do something
    }

});
```

**base.js**

```
import ApiQuery from './_apiquery';
require('./_username_availability');
export {ApiQuery};
```